# Verbs or phrases to buy something which are specifically for sale later?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

what is the verbs or phares stating that shop owners buy something which are specifically to be sold in future, chefs buy some ingredients which are specifically used to make foods to sell, or craftsman buy some row materials which are specifically used to made some artifects to be sold?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Buying a commodity a long time before it will be needed in order to guarantee the availability of supply, or to insulate oneself against future price rises, is known as **hedging.** Commodities bought in this way are the subject of a so-called **futures contract.**

For instance, many airlines hedge their jet fuel purchases in order to minimize the possibility of operating at a loss if the price of fuel goes up, especially in a highly volatile market. (This strategy works to the airlines' advantage when the price trend is upwards, but can be expensive if — as has the recently been the case for many airlines — the price trend is downwards after the purchase is made.)

If you are simply talking about buying now in order to have enough materials on hand to enable operations to continue a long time into the future, possible terms are **stockpiling, hoarding, building up one's inventory of raw supplies, bulk buying** or simply **buying/purchasing in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

Preorder- noun
An order for an item that has not yet been made commercially available.
Reference :http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preorder

Answer (score 1):

Goods purchased like this are called ***wholesale*** goods and the act of puchasing these goods is known as *buying wholesale*.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wholesale):

> Wholesaling, jobbing, or distributing is the sale of goods or merchandise to retailers; to industrial, commercial, institutional, or other professional business users; or to other wholesalers and related subordinated services.[1] In general, it is the sale of goods to anyone other than a standard consumer.
>
> According to the United Nations Statistics Division, "wholesale" is the resale (sale without transformation) of new and used goods to retailers, to industrial, commercial, institutional or professional users, or to other wholesalers, or involves acting as an agent or broker in buying merchandise for, or selling merchandise to, such persons or companies. Wholesalers frequently physically assemble, sort and grade goods in large lots, break bulk, repack and redistribute in smaller lots.[2] While wholesalers of most products usually operate from independent premises, wholesale marketing for foodstuffs can take place at specific wholesale markets where all traders are congregated.

Note though that this refers to the purchase of finished goods for retail sale to the public.  It doesn't necessarily cover the purchase of raw materials for the production of retail goods.  However a chef *may*, for example, purchase a large bag of flower wholesale because that bag of flower was sold by a wholesaler not open to the general public.  Wholesale purchases are often not subject to sales tax the way retail purchases are.